# Is Hijama(Cupping) related to black magic?

Tags: jinn, sihr, medical, evil-eye

As Salam Alikum,

Is Hijama helpful in removing black magic or sihr?

I read somewhere that after a jinn leaves a human body, the magic(sihr), remains back. How far is this correct?

Also, can cupping help in removing evil eye/magic/jinn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walecum assalam,

Actually some Raqyi do use Hijamah as well to treat black magic, but Hijama alone is not the Sunnah way of treating the black magic or removing the Jinn.

Hijama actually Boosts the Ruqya process somewhat though.

Actually there is nothing like Black or White magic. there is only Magic.  The Jinn can possess the body by his own will (as may be someone tease them or accidentally harmed them,so they possess a body) or Magic is used to control and put a jinn inside someone's body.

Ruqya is the ONLY Sunnah way to remove the Magic effect and Jinn. Once the jinn leaves the body, then the effect of Magic is also broken with it, but sometime the Jinns return as well, so raqyi has to make sure that the Jinn does not returns back.

Also, If someone has done magic ,then he is cured from it , then if the enemy does the magic again,then the victim can be possessed again as well. because Ruqya alone only is used to take out the effect of magic and jinn. there are other way to KEEP away from these effect as well.

If you need more info, then you can ask.

Comment: So basically, cupping is not related to ruqya?

Comment: no. it only has physical benefit, not spiritual or any relation with spiritual healing